# How can I reduce exaggerated wrinkles in a person's profile image with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photo-editing, portrait

I'm looking for a quick method for reducing wrinkles in an image.

Specifically for images that weren't taken professionally. So ones with highlights and shadows all over the place making it difficult to just brighten the area.

[image]

My current method is to just use the `Spot Healing Brush Tool` to remove the wrinkles completely after fixing the lighting as best I can.

**How can I reduce (but not remove) wrinkles in an image of a person?**

Comment: Honestly, there's a lot more wrong with that photo than just poor lighting and wrinkles (the camera shake is particularly obvious), and you probably can't fix it all. This is still an interesting how-to question, but the best *practical* solution is probably to retake a better photo if at all possible.

Comment: Agree with Ilmari Karonen comment. The overall color of the photo and contrast need to be corrected.

Comment: One tip. Find out more about frequency separation https://www.google.com/search?q=frequency+separation+photoshop

Comment: Nice tip @Rafael, definitely going to read up on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn to dodge and burn. There are many ways to do this, the 3 most common are:

- Dodge and Burn Tool
- Brush set to Lighten or Darken
- Curves Adjustment Masked In

---

**Dodge and Burn Tool**

Create a new layer with 50% gray set to Soft Light. Some people even create two of these layers. Name it/them Dodge and Burn.

[image]

Then use the Dodge and Burn tool to fix the wrinkles and then the layer Opacity for fine tuning. For wrinkle reduction you really only need Dodge. I set the Range to Midtones, Exposure to 10, Protect Tones activated and then in a few seconds brought it to this:

[image]

---

**Lighten Brush**

Create a layer the same was as above in the Dodge/Burn method. 50% gray, soft light. Then select a White Brush and change the Brush Blend mode to Lighten. Lower the Flow or Opacity down to like 10% and have at it:

[image]

---

**Curves Adjustment**

Create a Curves Adjustment layer and increase the midtones a little and if you want you can increase the shadows a tad too. A benefit of this method is the Curves will be adjustable so you can always change this later too (If you were needing to Burn then you'd do a second Curves Adjustment for Burning)

[image]

Then invert the mask and paint in where you want the adjustment to show:

[image]

---

This was quick but here's a quick gif showing before and after.

[image]

Comment: Definitely a good quality method of improvement thanks. Is it non-destructive? It looks like it is, just double-checking.

Comment: As long as you do them on New Layers like I explain then yes. If you take the Brush or Dodge tool directly to your image layer then no. @Dom